# Save the entire flot chart to image

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I am trying to save entire flot chart to image.  I found this link: [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616925/save-flot-graph-as-image), it works to some degree -- only save the curves. It didn't save the ticks on axis.  Any  help is appreciated.

Edit:
flot chart will create two canvases:

```
url = $("canvas")[0].toDataURL("image/png");
```

I converted the first one to image, and it contains just the curves for the graphs. Don't see ticks, don't y-axis label.

**Update:**

Found a solution by using [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas). First assign the container div to have id like "theChart".

```
<div class="demo-container" id="theChart">
    <!--<div style="vertical-align:top"><span style="float:left;vertical-align:top">Server Response in millisecond</span><span style="float:right;vertical-align:top">Http Response Rate</span></div> -->
    <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

Now we can create an image:

```
$('#theChart').html2canvas({
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        z = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        myWindow = window.open('', 'header', 'menubar=0', 'toolbar=0');
        myWindow.document.write('Right click to save image<br/><img src="' + z + '"/>');
    }
});
```

Comment: what code have you tried? show your code.